# Integrating video call feature in multiple modes

Tags: video, webrtc, voip

I am looking for open source application which could provide me with video call functionality so that I can embed it in my different projects.

Now embedding it into multiple projects would require it to be usable in following modes :-

- Web to web
- Web to mobile OR vice versa
- Mobile to mobile

While surfing I came across Signal api https://signal.org/download/
However, I have no idea how can I integrate it into my applications.

Could you please help me guide through this.